# What kind of Juniper tree has a straight, peeling trunk, relatively thin branches, and sharp blue-ish needles?

Tags: identification

There is this tree in my yard as well as in few other landscaped yards in my neighborhood. I assume it's a Juniper, perhaps a specific cultivar, but I cannot find any examples of it online.

It has a straight, peeling trunk, relatively thin branches compared to other junipers, and sharp, slightly blue-ish needles.

[image: Tree trunk and bark]
[image: Tree profile with thin branches]
[image: Tree needles]

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: Rochester, New York